# IntelliJ inspection syntax highlighting not updating after being fixed

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently updated intelliJ from a version from 2018 to the current version and now, the inspection syntax highlighting is wonky.

As I start to type something, for instance an assignment, I will get an inspection warning at the beginning.

`field.value =`

results in `Expression statement is not an assignment or call` which is obvious, because I haven't finished typing the assignment.

[image: Inspection on incomplete assignment]

When I finish typing the assignment, however, inspection doesn't recognize that this is now a valid assignment and the syntax highlighting doesn't go away.

[image: Inspection still on complete assignment]

If I simply highlight the inspected part (`field.value`) and then cut it away and immediately paste it back, IntelliJ recognizes it as correctly written and the syntax highlighting goes away.

The above example is with javascript, but this happens with everything. Everywhere. There is constantly incorrect, outdated syntax highlighting throughout my entire project that needs to be cut and pasted back in order to appear correctly.

Here is another example of the inspecting triggering on a "misspelled" word inside a string as I type it:

[image: String spelling error on partial word]

The word was finished and syntax highlight still shows an error on the beginning of the word.

This was not the case with the older version of IntelliJ that I was previously using.

I have tried "Invalidate Caches / restart" which will get rid of the current errors in syntax highlighting but doesn't prevent new ones from appearing.

What could be the problem here? How can I force IntelliJ to automatically reevaluate its syntax highlighting? How can I fix this?

**Update**

Based on request in comments with logs from `idea.log`:

```
2020-10-19 12:39:15,589 [12546211]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3  Build #IU-202.7660.26 
2020-10-19 12:39:15,589 [12546211]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2020-10-19 12:39:15,590 [12546212]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - OS: Windows 10 
2020-10-19 12:39:15,591 [12546213]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Last Action: EditorUp 
2020-10-19 12:39:15,591 [12546213]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Invalid range specified: (5, 1);  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid range specified: (5, 1); 
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.assertProperRange(TextRange.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.assertProperRange(TextRange.java:216)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.assertProperRange(TextRange.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.<init>(TextRange.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.<init>(TextRange.java:29)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString$mapRangeToHostRange$1.invoke(PartiallyKnownString.kt:189)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString.mapRangeToHostRange(PartiallyKnownString.kt:213)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString$split$2$2.invoke(PartiallyKnownString.kt:130)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString$split$2.invoke(PartiallyKnownString.kt:156)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString.split(PartiallyKnownString.kt:166)
    at com.intellij.microservices.url.references.UrlPksParser.splitUrlPath(UrlPksParser.kt:129)
    at com.intellij.microservices.url.references.UrlPksParser.parseFullUrl(UrlPksParser.kt:62)
    at com.intellij.microservices.url.references.UrlPathReferenceInjector.buildFullUrlReference(UrlPathReferenceInjector.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.javascript.microservices.JSUrlPathReferenceProvider.getReferencesByElement(JSUrlPathReferenceProvider.kt:17)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.getReferences(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:202)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.mapNotEmptyReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.doGetReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:145)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.lambda$getReferencesFromProviders$0(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:40)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager$1.compute(CachedValuesManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.lambda$getValueWithLock$1(CachedValueBase.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:71)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:236)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValuesManagerImpl.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManagerImpl.java:76)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:120)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:39)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:32)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSLiteralExpressionImpl.createRefs(JSLiteralExpressionImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSLiteralExpressionImpl.lambda$static$0(JSLiteralExpressionImpl.java:78)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiParameterizedCachedValue.doCompute(PsiParameterizedCachedValue.java:46)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.lambda$getValueWithLock$1(CachedValueBase.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:71)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:236)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiParameterizedCachedValue.getValue(PsiParameterizedCachedValue.java:35)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getParameterizedCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:81)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSLiteralExpressionImpl.getReferences(JSLiteralExpressionImpl.java:88)
    at com.jetbrains.nodejs.codeInsight.NodeCoreCodingAssistanceInspection.handleFileReferenceHolder(NodeCoreCodingAssistanceInspection.java:50)
    at com.jetbrains.nodejs.codeInsight.NodeCoreCodingAssistanceInspection.access$000(NodeCoreCodingAssistanceInspection.java:24)
    at com.jetbrains.nodejs.codeInsight.NodeCoreCodingAssistanceInspection$1.visitJSLiteralExpression(NodeCoreCodingAssistanceInspection.java:39)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSLiteralExpressionImpl.accept(JSLiteralExpressionImpl.java:128)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.acceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.createVisitorAndAcceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:56)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.runToolOnElements(LocalInspectionsPass.java:296)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$3(LocalInspectionsPass.java:265)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.forceAllowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:155)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.forceAllowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:147)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$4(LocalInspectionsPass.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:126)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:115)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$5(LocalInspectionsPass.java:264)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:149)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:162)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:162)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1110)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$wrapInReadActionAndIndicator$1(ApplierCompleter.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.wrapInReadActionAndIndicator(ApplierCompleter.java:117)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$compute$0(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.compute(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
2020-10-19 12:39:15,592 [12546214]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3  Build #IU-202.7660.26 
2020-10-19 12:39:15,592 [12546214]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2020-10-19 12:39:15,592 [12546214]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - OS: Windows 10 
2020-10-19 12:39:15,592 [12546214]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Last Action: EditorUp 
2020-10-19 12:39:19,268 [12549890]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - [+] Start SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-19 12:39:19,268 [12549890]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - Locating psi files for 0 documents: [] 
2020-10-19 12:39:19,268 [12549890]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - End SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-19 12:39:19,809 [12550431]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=parent, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Projects\xxxxxxx)RunManager took 15 ms 
2020-10-19 12:39:22,061 [12552683]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Flushing logs. 
2020-10-19 12:39:22,061 [12552683]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Scheduling next log flush in 60000 ms. 
2020-10-19 12:40:00,335 [12590957]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1 
2020-10-19 12:40:00,608 [12591230]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - [+] Start SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-19 12:40:00,608 [12591230]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - Locating psi files for 0 documents: [] 
2020-10-19 12:40:00,608 [12591230]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - End SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-19 12:40:01,085 [12591707]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=parent, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Projects\xxxxxxx)ArquillianContainersManager took 29 ms, RunManager took 12 ms
```

That leads me to believe there's a problem with the `SaveActionManager`... Investigating further.

**Update 2**:

Removed the `SaveActionManager` plugin and restarted which did not fix things, however, it lead to a more direct error that is specifically in the file that I'm currently editing and directly dealing with syntax highlighting:

```
2020-10-19 12:50:45,329 [ 122921]   INFO - ramework.JobViewEditorProvider - start JobViewEditorProvider 
2020-10-19 12:50:49,237 [ 126829]  ERROR - n.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass - In file: file://C:/Projects/xxxxxx/automation-test/cypress/integration/050-environments/140-xxxxxx.spec.js 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid range specified: (5, 1); 
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.assertProperRange(TextRange.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.assertProperRange(TextRange.java:216)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.assertProperRange(TextRange.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.<init>(TextRange.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange.<init>(TextRange.java:29)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString$mapRangeToHostRange$1.invoke(PartiallyKnownString.kt:189)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString.mapRangeToHostRange(PartiallyKnownString.kt:213)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString$split$2$2.invoke(PartiallyKnownString.kt:130)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString$split$2.invoke(PartiallyKnownString.kt:156)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PartiallyKnownString.split(PartiallyKnownString.kt:166)
    at com.intellij.microservices.url.references.UrlPksParser.splitUrlPath(UrlPksParser.kt:129)
    at com.intellij.microservices.url.references.UrlPksParser.parseFullUrl(UrlPksParser.kt:62)
    at com.intellij.microservices.url.references.UrlPathReferenceInjector.buildFullUrlReference(UrlPathReferenceInjector.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.javascript.microservices.JSUrlPathReferenceProvider.getReferencesByElement(JSUrlPathReferenceProvider.kt:17)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.getReferences(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:202)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.mapNotEmptyReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.doGetReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:145)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.lambda$getReferencesFromProviders$0(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:40)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager$1.compute(CachedValuesManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.lambda$getValueWithLock$1(CachedValueBase.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:71)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:236)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValuesManagerImpl.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManagerImpl.java:76)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:120)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:39)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:32)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSLiteralExpressionImpl.createRefs(JSLiteralExpressionImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSLiteralExpressionImpl.lambda$static$0(JSLiteralExpressionImpl.java:78)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiParameterizedCachedValue.doCompute(PsiParameterizedCachedValue.java:46)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.lambda$getValueWithLock$1(CachedValueBase.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:71)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:236)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiParameterizedCachedValue.getValue(PsiParameterizedCachedValue.java:35)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getParameterizedCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:81)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSLiteralExpressionImpl.getReferences(JSLiteralExpressionImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.highlighting.HyperlinkAnnotator.annotate(HyperlinkAnnotator.java:44)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.runAnnotators(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:136)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.visit(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:116)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.runVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:338)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.lambda$collectHighlights$5(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:277)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:297)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.lambda$analyzeByVisitors$6(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:300)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.analyze(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:598)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:300)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.lambda$analyzeByVisitors$6(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:300)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.analyze(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:96)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:300)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectHighlights(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:268)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectInformationWithProgress(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:214)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:80)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:54)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$1(PassExecutorService.java:399)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1110)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:391)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:367)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:365)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
2020-10-19 12:50:49,242 [ 126834]  ERROR - n.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass - IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3  Build #IU-202.7660.26 
2020-10-19 12:50:49,242 [ 126834]  ERROR - n.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2020-10-19 12:50:49,243 [ 126835]  ERROR - n.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass - OS: Windows 10 
2020-10-19 12:50:49,252 [ 126844]  ERROR - n.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass - Last Action: EditorEnter 
2020-10-19 12:50:51,908 [ 129500]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File C:\Users\xxxxx\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
```

**Update 3**:

Based on suggestion from comments, opened bug ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253270

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the log? (Help | Show Log in Finder)

Comment: Yes, actually. Updating with the logs now.

Comment: Probably you should file a bug report with the second exception, it seems like a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Comment: Done. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253270

Comment: Same issue in pycharm 2023.3.3 community edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an IntelliJ bug.

The advice from [Bas Leijdekkers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4510/bas-leijdekkers) guided me toward creating [a bug ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253270) which was marked as a duplicate of a bug that is being fixed in the next release. Thanks for the assistance Bas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! to go to File > setting > project:python-workspace(under"version control"),

then set your Project Interpreter from None to your current Python version,

and that may solve the case!